# Why Internal and Cycles are so different when rendering a duplifaced object with particle system?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, dupli-groups

One object is recreating another as dupliface instances. But those one which is being instanced has got *particle system* + *explode modifier*. Cycles renders OK, but Internal fails on this task, though its viewport shows right relationships between objects.

EDIT: I found how to make it work in Internal - just switch to **object** mode in render settings of *particle system* and keep it blank. Anyway I'm still curious why is it acting like that...

[image: Difference]

[image]